# I intentionally swallowed blood, but not with the intention to break the fast; does it still break my fast?

Tags: ramadan, sawm

I got a nosebleed today, and as I was running towards the sink, lots of blood came into my mouth, and it dripped like mad. I then washed my nose, and stopped the bleading. But in the process of doing so, I swallowed blood.

The reason I swallowed it:

1. I totally forgot that it was Ramadan, so I did NOT break the fast with an intention of breaking it. I just happened to do something that invalidates it, but By Allah, I did not swallow the blood to break my fast.
2. After researching, I found out that swallowing blood is Haram in Islam. I didn't know this before, and I didn't know that swallowing blood invalidates my fast, because I never thought about it before, and I never looked it up.
3. I swallowed the blood *intentionally*, because I totally forgot about Ramadan, and I thought that it wasn't Haram (because if I did know that, I would've never done it in the first place), let alone knowing that it invalidates my fast.

I looked this up, and the scholars all say that your fast will not be invalid if you do it unintentionally, but I swallowed it intentionally, but not with the intention of breaking the fast, so that's why I'm asking this here.

I'll be continuing my fast, but if someone tells me my fast was invalid, I will make up for it. If it didn't invalid my fast, I won't make up for it, because I'm not going to break my fast today.

---

As for you, "Azam", it is not possible to make up a day if the fast of that day was valid. The question here is whether it's considered as valid or not. So if I have to decide if this invalidates my fast or not, I first have to know the answer. Because if I have to make up for today, then I HAVE to eat right now, otherwise I'm Fasting for no reason.

Comment: You're totally confused. Anyways, just making up that day's fast seems good IMHO, to be on the safer side.

Comment: "*I swallowed it intentionally, but NOT with the intention of breaking the fast*". This is the summary of your question. Right?.. Then, I suggest you narrow down your scope to the sect which you belong to, to avoid dispute. And next time address the commenter by clicking the "add a comment" below the comment and calling the person with @ in the beginning. One more thing, you might not get answers here instantly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I totally forgot that it was Ramadan, so I did NOT break the fast with an intention of breaking it.

This belongs to the category of *eating forgetfully*. As a result, your fast should be valid because of the following Hadith:

> It was narrated from Abu Hurairah that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said:
>   "Whoever eats out of forgetfulness while fasting, let him complete his fast, for it is Allah Who has fed him and given him to drink."
>
> -Sunan Ibn Majah Book 7 Hadith 1743 (classed Sahih by Darussalam)

Moreover, Dr. Husam al-Din Ibn Musa `Afana, professor of principles of Islamic jurisprudence atAl-Quds University, Palestine, states the following:

> This hadith clearly shows that anybody who forgetfully eats or drinks during the daytime of Ramadan is to complete his fast and not to break it, nor does he have to fast another day for this day because his eating or drinking is sustenance from Allah. Actually, to unmindfully drink or eat during fasting does not affect it, because such a person is excused in Islam. This is further evidenced by the following hadith: "My Ummah will be excused for what they commit by mistake, forgetfulness, or what they were forced to do" (At-Tabarani, Ad-Darqutni and Al-Hakim in different wording.)
>
> source : http://www.onislam.net/english/ask-the-scholar/acts-of-worship/fasting/etiquettes-of-fasting/171724-advising-one-who-forgetfully-eats-in-ramadan.html

And Allah (SWT) knows best.

Comment: Good! This is the hadith which I was looking for without which I couldn't answer.

Comment: Notice that in madhab malik, the fast wold be broken and he had to qada. This is because malik differs between fasting in ramadan and sunna fasting other days.